# CSS crop an image with the same quality

Tags: html, css

At the moment I create a little upload page. On the page you can upload your image. Here is the link: [MyPage](http://skeptar.bplaced.net/upload/). Now I want to crop the image, but I want see more if the image and not only a little piece like now. This page is a very good example: [Page](http://pr0gramm.com/). One more negative point is the quality, I think the quality is even worse.

Here are the two pictures on the example page: [picture](http://pr0gramm.com/top/689570) if you look on the square over the real version with the same image it looks much better as on my page. And here is the other image: [picture](http://pr0gramm.com/top/689207). I hope you understood me.

Here is my Code:

```css
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.button-submit{
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    background-color: orange;
    color: black;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}

.button-submit:hover{
    color: orange;
    border: 2px solid orange;
    background-color: black;
}

.image{ 
    object-fit: none; /* Do not scale the image */
    object-position: center; /* Center the image within the element */
    height: 128px;
    width: 128px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="meine.css" >
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php include "connection.php" ?>
        <h1>Lade dein Bild hoch</h1>
        
        <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" class="button-submit" name="submit">
        </form>
        <?php
            
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM bilder";
            $result=mysqli_query($db,$sql);
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                echo "<img class='image' src='$row[bild_pfad]' alt='$row[bild_name]' style='$row[bild_werte]'>";
            } 
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The effect you want is to scale the image so it covers its dimensions. You can easily adapt your CSS to do this by changing your image's `object-fit` property; like so:

```
.image { object-fit: cover; }
```